# Shift Entity Framework .Take() operation to end of Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Currently we do our paging operations in the DataRepository when getting the collection from the context. This means that the Query we get from the context already has the .Skip() and .Take() calls applied. Controllers then do their business logic or filtering operations without having to worry about paging.

The issue is that when you do .Where() statements after the .Take() statement you are only filtering on the Page, not the entire Table before the Operation. Is there a way I can call .Skip() and .Take() (or another method I can use) to specify that they those operations should happen last when the Query is evaluated, even though the .Where calls haven't been made yet, or am I going to have to refactor this to call .Skip() and .Take() after all the other operations?

Comment: I think you're going to have to show a sample of the query for us to help.

Comment: It is probably better to redesign your program flow, but you could always write an `ExpressionVisitor` to pick up the `Skip`/`Take` and move them to the end after you have added the `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

Different order of calling Where and Take method means different dataset. You may need a new method to accept filter and call Where before Skip and Take

```
public static IQueryable<T> PaginationAfterWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Func<T, bool> where, int skip, int take)
    {
        return queryable.Where(x => where(x)).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    }
```